# How to upload HTML File(contains img,css and js) to Contentful (CMS)?

Tags: ios, contentful

I have created a sample HTML(contains js, css and images) guide. I want to upload this html file to CMS(content management System) to edit content later. After that I will retrieve html content from CMS System and load it in my iOS app. So my guide will not be static and I don't have to rebuild for my iOS app every time. I reviewed content-ful api service, but can't find a way to upload html file. is this possible ?
 Please help me on this? or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not unfortunately possible. In your case it's easier to add content manually to your Contentul space and then retrieve the content within web application using [JavaScript SDK](https://www.contentful.com/ecosystem/javascript-sdk-for-cda/). If you're going to create iOS app as well, then [Objective-C SDK](https://www.contentful.com/ecosystem/objective-c-sdk-for-cda/) and [Swift SDK](https://www.contentful.com/ecosystem/swift-sdk-for-cda/) might be useful for utilizing the content in future.